# Cannot edit the preferences of the Gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, preferences

After I restarted my computer today, I found the color of my Gnome-terminal looks different from usual. And I cannot edit the profile preferences or add a new profile to edit.

here is the snapshot, every item of the configuration gray out so I can't modify them.

[image]

I have reinstalled the Gnome-terminal by apt-get, but it still doesn't work. Can Anyone help me? Thanks!!!

**My environment : Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS**

**GNOME Terminal version : 3.6.2**

Comment: Maybe the standard `sudo chown -R $USER: ~` executed from your account to get back file ownership of your entire home directory can help? It would solve a problem caused by messed up permissions, maybe because of `dconf` was ran as root or something like that.

Comment: I converted my comment into an answer. Please accept it by clicking the grey tick symbol on the left of it to mark your question as solved. Also make sure to have read our little [tour] page, where you can learn the most important things about how our site works in less than two minutes. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something messed up your home directory ownership and therefore `gnome-terminal` is not able to properly get and set configuration values.

Probably this was caused by running any kind of `dconf` editor or another application with `sudo` that changed some file ownerships.

The solution is very simple and can also be applied to a load of other problems:

**Get back the ownership of all files and folders in your home directory:**

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~
```